# SpringMVC Integration SpringBatch transaction have a problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

After springbatch integrates the mvc import interface, the transaction is abnormal, and the service layer is injected into the job to execute the transaction problem.
**BatchController.class**

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/job")
    public class BatchController {

        private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        private final Job batchGenerateJob;

        @Autowired
        public BatchController(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job batchGenerateJob) {
            this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
            this.batchGenerateJob = batchGenerateJob;
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/{cid}")
        public AjaxObj batchgenbycid(@PathVariable String cid) {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(cid) || Integer.parseInt(cid) == 0) {
                return ResultUtil.fail("请在左侧点击栏目");
            }
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("channelId", cid)
                    .addString("siteId", Integer.toString(1))
                    .addString("runtime", "最后执行时间：" + DateFormatUtils.format(new Date(), "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"))
                    .toJobParameters();
            try {
                jobLauncher.run(batchGenerateJob, jobParameters);
            } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JobRestartException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ResultUtil.success();
        }
    }
```

** BatchNewsConfig.class **

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchNewsConfig implements StepExecutionListener {
    public static final String SITE_ID = "siteId";
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channelId";

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;


    private Map<String, JobParameter> parameterMap;

    @Autowired
    public BatchNewsConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job batchGenerateJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchGenerateJob")
                //获取站点信息
                .start(getSiteParameterStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step getSiteParameterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("getChannelIdParameterStep")
                .listener(this)
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        String channelStr = parameterMap.get(CHANNEL_ID).toString();
                        Integer cid = Integer.valueOf(channelStr);
                        System.out.println(cid);
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }).build();
    }



    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        parameterMap = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

** Console output Can run**

````
 16:37:42,840  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:133 - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=batchGenerateJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{channelId=368, siteId=1, runtime=最后执行时间：2018_12_20_16_37_42}]
    16:37:42,913  INFO SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [getChannelIdParameterStep]
    368
    16:37:42,950  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:136 - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=batchGenerateJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{channelId=368, siteId=1, runtime：2018_12_20_16_37_42}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
    ```
    ### When I injected the Service, I executed the error again.
    **  IChannelBatchService **
    ```java
    import cn.dahe.model.Channel;

    import java.util.Set;

    public interface IChannelBatchService{

        Channel get(int id);

        Set<Integer> getAllChildrenByCid(int cid);
    }
````

**  ChannelBatchService **

```
import cn.dahe.dao.IChannelDao;
import cn.dahe.model.Channel;
import cn.dahe.service.IChannelBatchService;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Service("channelBatchService")
public class ChannelBatchService  implements IChannelBatchService {

    @Resource
    private IChannelDao channelDao;


    @Override
    public Channel get(int id) {
        return channelDao.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getAllChildrenByCid(int cid) {
        return getChildrenCid(cid, Sets.newHashSet());
    }

    /**
     * @param cid
     * @param cidsSet
     */
    private Set<Integer> getChildrenCid(int cid, Set<Integer> cidsSet) {
        cidsSet.add(cid);
        List<Channel> channels = channelDao.getChannelByPid(cid);
        if (channels != null && !channels.isEmpty()) {
            for (Channel channel : channels) {
                cidsSet.add(channel.getId());
                cidsSet = getChildrenCid(channel.getId(), cidsSet);
            }
        }
        return cidsSet;
    }
}
```

**add service**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchNewsConfig implements StepExecutionListener {
    public static final String SITE_ID = "siteId";
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channelId";

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;


    private final IChannelBatchService iChannelBatchService;

    private Map<String, JobParameter> parameterMap;

    public BatchNewsConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, JobRepository jobRepository, IChannelBatchService iChannelBatchService) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.iChannelBatchService = iChannelBatchService;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job batchGenerateJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchGenerateJob")

                .start(getSiteParameterStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step getSiteParameterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("getChannelIdParameterStep")
                .listener(this)
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        String channelStr = parameterMap.get(CHANNEL_ID).toString();
                        Integer cid = Integer.valueOf(channelStr);
                        System.out.println(cid);
                        Channel channel = iChannelBatchService.get(cid);
                        System.out.println(channel);
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }).build();
    }


    /**
     * 执行前获取JobParameters
     *
     * @param stepExecution
     */
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        parameterMap = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

** Console output **

```
  16:48:45,539  INFO JobRepositoryFactoryBean:183 - No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
16:48:45,674  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:195 - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
16:48:45,735  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:133 - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=batchGenerateJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{channelId=368, siteId=1, runtime=2018_12_20_16_48_45}]
16:48:45,792  INFO SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [getChannelIdParameterStep]
368
16:48:45,811 ERROR AbstractStep:229 - Encountered an error executing step getChannelIdParameterStep in job batchGenerateJob
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@b675ab] for key [{
    CreateTime:"2018-12-20 16:48:36",
    ActiveCount:2,
    PoolingCount:0,
    CreateCount:2,
    DestroyCount:0,
    CloseCount:18,
    ConnectCount:20,
    Connections:[
    ]
}] bound to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.get(Unknown Source)
    at cn.dahe.batch.BatchNewsConfig$1.execute(BatchNewsConfig.java:88)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@b675ab] for key [{
    CreateTime:"2018-12-20 16:48:36",
    ActiveCount:2,
    PoolingCount:0,
    CreateCount:2,
    DestroyCount:0,
    CloseCount:18,
    ConnectCount:20,
    Connections:[
    ]
}] bound to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:516)
    ... 26 more
16:48:45,827  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:136 - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=batchGenerateJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{channelId=368, siteId=1, runtime=2018_12_20_16_48_45}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

** prom.xml **

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AOP end -->

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- LOGGING end -->
        <!-- GENERAL UTILS begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- google java library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TEST begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.jpush.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpush-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibeetl</groupId>
            <artifactId>beetl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: public class BatchNewsConfig implements StepExecutionListener  The task implements the StepExecutionListener and then injects the implementation class. When the implementation class is executed, the error is reported.

Comment: please update the question with more information, do not just write comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have multiple transaction managers. In such a case, you can specify the transaction manager for tasklets explicitly.

```
<tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
```

`@EnableBatchProcessing`  automatically registers a transaction manager. You can change transaction manager that batch uses simply by implementing the `BatchConfigurer` interface.